# How to release Product flavours demo vs full in play store

Tags: android, gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin, apk-expansion-files

I want to release two apks demo_release.apk and full_release.apk to play store

But i am getting error like change versionCode of app

How to manage version codes for two different versions

I have already app_release.apk is available in play store with versionCode 52.

What i want is to release both apks demo and full version in play store.
But i am too confused about how it actually works and how the users will be able to download demo and full version of app

This is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
  }
 }

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.credihealth.android"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 52
    versionName "4.2.1.1"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
}

productFlavors {

    demo {
        applicationIdSuffix ".demo"
    }

    full {
        applicationIdSuffix ".full"
    }
}
}

 repositories {
mavenCentral()
flatDir {
    dirs 'libs'
}


    }

dependencies {
compile(name: "youtube_player_api", ext: "jar")
// this line must be included to integrate with Firebase
// this line must be included to use FCM

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
compile 'com.roomorama:caldroid:2.2.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
compile 'com.uncopt:android.justified:1.0'
compile 'com.yayandroid:LocationManager:2.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.1'
compile 'com.hbb20:ccp:1.7.6'
compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
compile 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.6.0@aar'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1'
compile 'com.stepstone.stepper:material-stepper:3.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
fullCompile 'com.twilio:video-android:1.3.0'
 }

 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to manage version codes for two different versions

You can customize the version code for each flavor.
For example:

```
productFlavors {
    demo {
        applicationIdSuffix ".demo"
        versionCode XX
    }
    full {
        applicationIdSuffix ".full"
        versionCode XX
    }
}
```

> What i want is to release both apks demo and full version in play store. But i am too confused about how it actually works and how the users will be able to download demo and full version of app

It is not related to build.gradle config and it depends by your choices.

Comment: @ShailendraSachan but what does it mean? There are 2 apks and each one has one version code.

Comment: demo with version code 1 and full with version code 1 cannot exist  right at the same time.So i have to assign different version code for two flavours demo with version code 1 and full with version code 2 . Now how will i update the app next time demo with version code 3 and full with version code 4

Comment: @ShailendraSachan It depends by what you want. It is the way to assign a version code to each flavor. Then as you want to use the different apks it is not clear and it is not related to the build.gradle. It depends if you want to install both in the same device, if they have the same package name...